# Does ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheet Distinguish Between Hard-Coded Ranges and CONCATENATEd Ranges

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

When using the ARRAYFORMULA function in Google Sheets, hardcoding the target range in the below formula works as intended:

```
=ArrayFormula(Sheet1!$FH$3:Sheet1!$GH$3)
```

The same for ARRAYCONSTRAIN:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(Sheet1!$FH$3:Sheet1!$GH$3,1,27)
```

These formulas fail when the range value is dynamic using CONCATENATE with other nested functions:

```
=ArrayFormula(CONCATENATE(CELL("address",OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address",INDEX(Sheet1!3:3,,MATCH(TODAY(),Sheet1!3:3,1)))),0,-26)),":",CELL("address",INDEX(Sheet1!3:3,,MATCH(TODAY(),Sheet1!3:3,1)))))
```

The above formula returns just the referenced range (i.e. "Sheet1!$FH$3:Sheet1!$GH$3") and not the range values.  I've tried using curly-brackets `{` and `}` and also `ctrl-shift-enter`.

Is there a way to use dynamic ranges constructed with `CONCATENATE` or similar functions (e.g. `JOIN`) with the `ARRAYFORMULA` or `ARRAYCONSTRAIN` functions to retrieve the range of cell values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are good to go only with:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Sheet1!$FH$3:$GH$3)
```

no need to repeat the sheet name twice

and when constructing the range you always need to use `INDIRECT` like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("Sheet1!FH3:GH3"))
```

> The above formula returns just the referenced range (i.e. "Sheet1!$FH$3:Sheet1!$GH$3") and not the range values

in your case try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(CELL("address", OFFSET(INDIRECT(
 CELL("address", INDEX(Sheet1!3:3,, MATCH(TODAY(), Sheet1!3:3, 1)))), 0, -26)),":", 
 CELL("address", INDEX(Sheet1!3:3,, MATCH(TODAY(), Sheet1!3:3, 1))))))
```

which could be reduced to:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT(CELL("address", OFFSET(INDIRECT(
 CELL("address", INDEX(Sheet1!3:3,, MATCH(TODAY(), Sheet1!3:3, 1)))), 0, -26))&":"& 
 CELL("address", INDEX(Sheet1!3:3,, MATCH(TODAY(), Sheet1!3:3, 1)))))
```

Comment: Thanks.  Both suggestions return a #REF error for the INDIRECT function:  "Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is 'Sheet1!$FH$3:Sheet1!$GH$3'. It is not a valid cell/range reference."

When tracing the error from an earlier attempt, I noticed that Google Sheets help on the function specified that INDIRECT is for a cell reference rather than a range (i.e. "Returns the requested information about the **specified cell**.")

Comment: yeah, as mentioned already... a valid range reference would be: `Sheet1!FH3:GH3` can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Per your suggestion, removing the duplicate 'Sheet1!' in the 'CONCATENATE'd 'CELL' functions seems to have resolved the problem.  When the range is hardcoded, the duplicate 'Sheet1!' name for the end of the range doesn't make a difference.